# Beamer: default block not displayed

Tags: beamer, block

I am currently using Beamer to create a presentation. I'd like to use blocks, as I already did several times in the past, but it seems not to work properly. For instance, the following example displays in dark blue 'Title' and in black 'Example', with no background at all.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Title}
Example
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I know how to customize block environments, but I'd like to understand why the default one is not working as I was expecting. Please correct me if this is the normal behaviour of blocks using Pittsburgh theme.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks perfectly normal. See also the example on page 149 of the manual, no background on the blocks there.

`beamerthemePittsburgh.sty` contains just

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /Users/joseph/Documents/LaTeX/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemePittsburgh.sty,v d02a7cf4d8ae 2010/06/17 09:11:41 rivanvx $


\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]

\useinnertheme{circles}

\mode
<all>
```

So it looks like it uses the same colours as the default colour theme, which also doesn't have any background colour on the blocks.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Do you by chance know the colour value of the dark blue used in this theme?

Comment: @dostoevskij It's the same as the default theme. I'll have to look in the source code.

Comment: @dostoevskij From `beamercolorthemedefault.sty` it looks like `\definecolor{blueish}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}` should be the blue colour used there, though when I tested it looked a bit darker. When I sampled a screenshot in Krita I got (R,G,B) = (51, 51, 178).

Comment: The first one you suggested seems the same used in the default theme to me. Thank you SO much!